# Incompatible types with pointer and linked list remove function

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm getting this error. Please help!

3.c: In function main:

3.c:92: error: incompatible types when assigning to type struct prcmd_t * from type prcmd_t

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct pr_struct{
        int owner;
        int burst_time;
        struct pr_struct *next_prcmd;
} prcmd_t;
static prcmd_t *pr_head = NULL;
static prcmd_t *pr_tail = NULL;
static int pending_request = 0;
static pthread_mutex_t prmutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;


int add_queue(prcmd_t *node)
{       pthread_mutex_lock(&prmutex);
        //code
        prcmd_t *curNode = pr_head;
        if(pr_head == NULL) { pr_head = node; return;}
        while(curNode->next_prcmd)
        {
              curNode = curNode->next_prcmd;
        }
        curNode->next_prcmd = node;

        //
        pending_request++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&prmutex);
        return(0);
}

**//inprogress
int remove_queue(prcmd_t **node)
{
    printf("prenull");
    pthread_mutex_lock(&prmutex);
    prcmd_t *tempNode;
    if(node == NULL)
    {
        //your code
        printf("Queue is empty");
        //
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&prmutex);
        return(-1);
    }
    else
    {
    printf("in else");
        //your code
        tempNode =(*node)->next_prcmd;
        free(node);
        //
        pending_request--;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&prmutex);
        return(0);
    }
}
//end progress**


int main()
{

    if (pr_head == NULL)
    {

        printf("List is empty!\n\n");
    }

    int i=0;
    int length = 4;
    prcmd_t *pr[length];
    for(i =0;i<length;i++)
    {
        pr[i] = (prcmd_t*)malloc(sizeof(prcmd_t));
        pr[i]->owner = i+1;
        pr[i]->burst_time = i + 2;
        add_queue(pr[i]);
    }


    prcmd_t *curNode = pr_head;

    while(curNode)
    {
        printf("%i  %i\n", curNode->owner,curNode->burst_time);
        curNode = curNode->next_prcmd;
    }
**//something is messed up here i think.
    curNode = *pr_head;
    remove_queue(&curNode);
//**

    while(curNode)
    {
        printf("%i  %i\n", curNode->owner,curNode->burst_time);
        curNode = curNode->next_prcmd;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

curNode is of type `prcmd_t *` (pointer to prcmd_t) and `pr_head` is also of type `prcmd_t *` so they are in the same level of reference, but you are trying to assign the value pointed by `pr_head` (which is of type `prcmd_t`) to `curNode` (which is of type `prcmd_t *`) and this is the incompatibility.

It is not clear to me what you are trying to do, but a correct syntax is either

```
curNode = pr_head;
```

or

```
memcpy(curNode, pr_head, sizeof(prcmd_t));
```